# how to position subheader right under header

Tags: html, css, positioning

This may be a silly question, but what is the best way to position a subheader right under a main header?  I have a main header (h1) and the css is below:

```css
h1 {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

I want to put a subheader directly underneath it, but am unsure how to position it without specifying top: "x" px;

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have two "position:" properties set in your &lt;h1&gt; CSS. Anyways, what do you mean? You could put your h1 and h2 elements in a div together and then edit the padding/margins/positioning however you like.

Comment: The best way would be to use relative positioning and putting the subheader below in the html markup

Comment: Place them both in a div and add the following styling to the div:
    `display: flex;`
   `flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no silly questions! we all started exactly where you are :) First off as Trevor has said you have 2 position properties assigned to this element when you can only assign one. Second I would not use absolute or relative positioning to accomplish what you want here since it is a bit heavy handed. Also using absolute positioning + translate 50% is not completely friendly to some browsers. The best solution in this case would be to wrap the heading and your sub heading inside of a parent div tag and assign that parent div tag the CSS property of text-align: center. The reason for this is your parent div will be a block level element and span the entire width of the container, then adding text-align: center will center all inline children elements within that parent.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

code pen:
http://codepen.io/chasereckling/pen/gwJkgN

```
<div>
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <h2>SUB HEADING</h2>
</div>

<style>
    div {text-align: center;}
</style>
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be an option, using a wrapper

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
h1,
h4 {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <h4>Test</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing CSS is a bit too much for that purpose, that centering can be done much easier using `text-align: center`, and then you can simply do the same for the subtitle, plus adjust the margins. If you want the subtitle  still closer to the `h1`, use `line-height: 1em` (or any other value that fits your needs):

```css
h1 {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
```